# I don’t understand the iteration . how does the loop work here?

Tags: python

I am confused with how does the loop work for this code ? I am learning python first time. can someone show me each loop iteration ?

Code:

```
a = 0
for i in range(5):
    a = a + 1
  
    for j in range (5):
        a = a + 1
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you understand?

```
i = 0
a + 1  --> a =1
j  = 0 ~ 4
a + 1, 1, 1, 1, 1   --> a = 6

i = 1
a  + 1 --> a =7
j  = 0 ~ 4
a + 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 --> a = 12
....

finish

a = 30
```

Simple, try it yourself.

```
import time

a = 0
for i in range(5):
    a = a + 1
    print('i:', i, 'a:', a)
    time.sleep(1)
    for j in range(5):
        a = a + 1
        print('j:', j, 'a:', a)
        time.sleep(1)
```